# C# Filter text from file

Tags: c#, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of text like this based on the 4 last characters.

```
John Doe         123456789 CD MM
Jane Doe         789456132 AB FM
```

So if I set the filter to MM I then I shouldn't see Jane Doe.

Comment: How are you displaying the result? Do you have a datagrid for example?

Comment: I'm displaying all the text in a richtextbox.

Comment: Does you array contain the entire line "john doe 1234...." all in one entry or do you use a class to hold that data in separate properties such as name, etc.?

Comment: Have you even tried googling this one? It's a "VERY" common question you know

Comment: I just managed to cut it down into separate properties. name,id,tag,sex

Comment: Of course I tried googling this, but English is not my strong side so I wasn't quite sure how to phrase it.

Comment: @DevEstacion Could you perhaps link me then?

Comment: @user3478897 Look at your answers on the question, also post how `John Doe         123456789 CD MM` is composed, is it a string or seperate properties in a class.

Comment: @DevEstacion I answered that question earlier.

Comment: @user3478897 I've tried answering it based on the details you've given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) let you check if last characters are the ones you want.

```
var source = new [] { "John Doe  123456789 CD MM", "Jane Doe 789456132 AB FM" };
var filtered = source.Where(s => s.EndsWith("MM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

So based from your comments,

```
John Doe         123456789 CD MM
Jane Doe         789456132 AB FM
```

They are now seperated in properties, so I'm presuming you have a class structure like this.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }
}
```

And you have either a `List<Person>` or Person[] to store your collection. You can filter it by sex by using Linq query. Do it like this.

```
        Person[] coll = new Person[] 
        {
            new Person
            {
                ID = 123456789,
                Name = "John Doe",
                Tag = "CD",
                Sex = "MM"
            },
            new Person
            {
                ID = 123456789,
                Name = "Jane Doe",
                Tag = "AB",
                Sex = "FM"
            }
        };

        var filteredSex = coll.Where(x => x.Sex == "MM");
```

You can even make `Tag` and `Sex` as Enum values, declare it like this.

```
public enum Sex
{
    MM,
    FM
}

public enum Tag
{
    CD,
    AB
}
```

Change your Person class to

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Tag Tag { get; set; }

    public Sex Sex { get; set; }
}
```

and assign it like this.

```
        Person[] coll = new Person[] 
        {
            new Person
            {
                ID = 123456789,
                Name = "John Doe",
                Tag = Tag.CD,
                Sex = Sex.MM
            },
            new Person
            {
                ID = 123456789,
                Name = "Jane Doe",
                Tag = Tag.AB,
                Sex = Sex.FM
            }
        };

        var filteredSex = coll.Where(x => x.Sex == Sex.MM);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] source = { "John Doe  123456789 CD MM", "Jane Doe 789456132 AB FM" };

foreach(var item in source)
{
    if(item.EndsWith("MM"))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

or you can use LINQ

// This will give you a list of items containing strings ending with MM
var result = source.Where(x=> x.EndsWith("MM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways you could do this. One is already posted using LINQ. Here is a straightforward way of doing it. This is not an optimal solution, and C# offers lots more to ways to make it better, but I meant to make it simple for you.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication18
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Students s1 = new Students();
            s1.name = "John Doe";
            s1.age = 12m;
            s1.tag = "MM";

            Students s2 = new Students();
            s2.name = "Su";
            s2.age = 12m;
            s2.tag = "XX";

            Students s3 = new Students();
            s3.name = "Jane Doe";
            s3.age = 12m;
            s3.tag = "FM";

            Students[] arr = new Students[3];
            arr[0] = s1;
            arr[1] = s2;
            arr[2] = s3;


            //Main logic
            string result = "";
            //loop in all array elements
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetUpperBound(0)+1 ; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i].tag == "MM") //Choose 0, 1 or more enteries with MM in tag
                {
                    result = result + arr[i].name + " " + 
                                      arr[i].age.ToString() + " " + 
                                      arr[i].tag +
                                      "  Position:" + i.ToString() + 
                                      Environment.NewLine;
                }

            }

            if (result != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            Console.Read();

        }
    }

    public class Students
    {
        public string name;
        public decimal age;
        public string tag;
    }
}
```